# How to pass data from angular to jquery when the http request is ready

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs

I am newbie to angular and javascript, so I need an advice. I am trying to make dynamically changed timepicker. When user chooses the value in datepicker I want my app to change timepicker disabled value dynamically. But the issue is when I am sending angular request to the server, it passes to jquery as empty. How can I made angular to wait until request is done?

JAVA code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/clientTrainingTime")
public class ClientTrainingTimeResources {
@RequestMapping(value = "/init", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<String> init () {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("13:00");
    list.add("14:00");
    list.add("15:00");
    list.add("16:00");
    return list;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<String> update () {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("17:00");
    list.add("18:00");
    list.add("19:00");
    list.add("21:00");
    return list;
}
```

}

HTML code

```
<form:input type="text" id="datepicker" path="workoutDate" cssClass="form-control"/>
<label>Time: </label>
<form:input type="text" id="timepicker" path="workoutTime" cssClass="form-control"/>
```

JQUERY code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var disabledTime = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="clientTrainingTimeCtrl"]')).scope().disabledTime;
        console.log('js disabledTime.length = ' + disabledTime.length);
        for (var i=0; i<disabledTime.length; i++) {
            console.log('js disabledTime[' + i + '] ' + disabledTime[i]);
        }
        $('#timepicker').timepicker({
            'minTime': '10:00',
            'maxTime': '22:00',
            'showDuration': true,
            'timeFormat': 'H:i',
            'show2400': true,
            'step': 60,
            'disableTimeRanges' : disabledTime
        });
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
                var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="clientTrainingTimeCtrl"]')).scope();
                scope.updateData(date);
                var disabledTime = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="clientTrainingTimeCtrl"]')).scope().disabledTime;
                console.log('js disabledTime.length = ' + disabledTime.length);
                for (var i=0; i<disabledTime.length; i++) {
                    console.log('js disabledTime[' + i + '] ' + disabledTime[i]);
                }
                $('#timepicker').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disabledTime);
            }
        });
    });
```

ANGULAR code

```
var clientTrainingTimeApp = angular.module ("clientTrainingTimeApp", []);
clientTrainingTimeApp.controller("clientTrainingTimeCtrl", function ($scope, $http, Time) {

    $scope.disabledTime = [];
    $scope.init = function () {
       var timePromise = Time.getTime();
       timePromise.then(function(result) {
            var temp = result;
            $scope.disabledTime = createArray(temp);
           //In this part disabledTime.length = 2
           console.log('disabledTime.length = ' + $scope.disabledTime.length);
           for (var i=0; i<$scope.disabledTime.length; i++) {
               console.log('disabledTime[' + i + '] ' + $scope.disabledTime[i]);
           }
        });
        //In this part disabledTime.length = 0
        console.log('disabledTime.length = ' + $scope.disabledTime.length);
        for (var i=0; i<$scope.disabledTime.length; i++) {
            console.log('disabledTime[' + i + '] ' + $scope.disabledTime[i]);
        }
    };

    $scope.updateData = function (date) {
        //Implement later
    }
});
clientTrainingTimeApp.factory('Time', function($http) {
    function getTime() {
        return $http.get('/eGym/rest/clientTrainingTime/init')
            .then(function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });
    }
        return { getTime: getTime }
});

var createArray = function (temp) {
    var result = [];
    var indexOfResultArray = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < temp.length; indexOfResultArray++) {
        result[indexOfResultArray] = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++, i++){
            result[indexOfResultArray][j] = temp[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

And output

```
[Log] disabledTime.length = 0 (controller.js, line 120)
[Log] js disabledTime.length = 0 (startTraining, line 113)
[Log] disabledTime.length = 2 (controller.js, line 114)
[Log] disabledTime[0] 13:00,14:00 (controller.js, line 116)
[Log] disabledTime[1] 15:00,16:00 (controller.js, line 116)
```

I have followed advices in the other topics but they don`t help me. As you can see the jquery part gets the disabledTime array earlier than the http get request in angular is finished. Maybe I have another way to do the same thing that I need.
Thanks for attention.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with AngularJS code? It seems you would want to use one or the other.  You javascript functions should be part of scope controller...not in jquery.

Comment: Could you help me to set the disabledTimeRanges in scope controller?

Comment: The general approach is to encapsulate the jQuery in an Angular directive. See [AngularJS Developers Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the right result with the code below, using jquery code in angular:

```
var timePromise = Time.getTime();
       timePromise.then(function(result) {
            var temp = result;
            $scope.disabledTime = createArray(temp);
           $(function () {
               $('#timepicker').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', $scope.disabledTime);
           });
           console.log('disabledTime.length = ' + $scope.disabledTime.length);
           for (var i=0; i<$scope.disabledTime.length; i++) {
               console.log('disabledTime[' + i + '] ' + $scope.disabledTime[i]);
           }
        });
```